# Change layout of ALV tree programmatically

Tags: treeview, abap, alv

I want to change the layout of a `cl_gui_alv_tree` programmatically. My current approach is not working. This is my code so far, executed in screen's PBO:

```
  CALL METHOD gs_0700-s_tree-r_tree->delete_all_nodes
    EXCEPTIONS
      failed            = 1
      cntl_system_error = 2
      OTHERS            = 3.
  IF sy-subrc <> 0.
    MESSAGE ID sy-msgid TYPE sy-msgty NUMBER sy-msgno
      WITH sy-msgv1 sy-msgv2 sy-msgv3 sy-msgv4.
  ENDIF.

  PERFORM load_new_tree_nodes.

  ls_vari-report   = gs_0700-repid.
  ls_vari-handle   = 'TREE'.
  ls_vari-variant  = '/new_variant'

  (...)

  CALL METHOD gs_0700-s_tree-r_tree->set_variant_key
    EXPORTING
      is_variant = ls_vari.

  CALL METHOD gs_0700-s_tree-r_tree->column_optimize.
  CALL METHOD gs_0700-s_tree-r_tree->update_calculations.

  CALL METHOD gs_0700-s_tree-r_tree->frontend_update.
```

The tree is redrawn and new nodes are loaded. Even the columns get optimized. Everything changes but not the layout variant. It looks always like `/default` layout variant I set with the `set_table_for_first_display` method during init of the tree. I created the variant `/new_variant` and I can load it via the toolbar.

Is there some other way to change the layout variant of a tree programmatically?

Comment: did u try naming  `ls_vari-variant  = '/NEW_VARIANT'` like so? Capitalization is often an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `SET_TABLE_FOR_FIRST_DISPLAY` method with parameter `I_DEFAULT = space`?

Default setting will be `'X'` which results in always displaying the default variant.

Comment: Could you please tell us if any of these answers have been helpful to you?